# is @"/dev/null" a valid path on the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using this class as a microphone detection: https://github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer and it works fine in the simulator but that doesn't work on the device.

peak power is always 0.000001 when testing on iPhone.

I don't know if `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];` is a valid path on the device, anyone?

Thanx

Comment: 3rd party apps work in a sandbox. They don't have access to files outside of the sandbox. The simulator doesn't have such restrictions like a real device does.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a similar use of the library
    /dev/null
is not a valid path in the device you need to use a writable one, like one on temp or documents inside the app.

Comment: It makes sense. But somewhow it still don't work. I've changed the directory to this `NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf", [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"], @"cache"];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];` and still don't work.

Comment: try this one:

`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
`
and then append the file

Comment: It returns the same directory of my previous code `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/278DFA56-2E41-44C4-8BA2-A9886A5F68C8/Documents` . Did not work too. ; (

Comment: @AntonioJunior Never use `NSHomeDirectory()` to build a path to the Documents folder in iOS. It will give the wrong path on new versions of iOS. Use the code Pablo gave.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I'm using it know. Just like Pablo said. I'm appending the file and after 3 seconds I delete this file. This is just to make sure is a valid path. It really creates and deletes my file, but it still don't work. This code works great on simulator.

Comment: Should I set something in info.plist to work on device?

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

and of course, I replaced @"dev/null" and after NSHomeDirectory for the code @Pablo Carrillo Alvarez gave.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

; )
thank you all.